# Make border with opacity around (background) image

Tags: css, html

I want a border **around** my image which is translucent showing 'background' (i.e. not the picture). As the css order is content, padding, border, margin, so I would expect the border around my picture-content, but probably because my picture is set as background (to make it scale) it does not work as I expected. Now it shows parts of my picture through my lightgrey border, see e.g.:
[image]

and

[image]

How do I get my border around my picture?

```css
body {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0 0;
 padding: 0 0;
}

.overlay {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #808080;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #f00;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 height: 40vh;
 width: 100vw;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}

.overlay .item-image {
 border-radius: 5px;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 min-width: 45vw;
 width: 45vw;
 margin-left: 4vw;
 border: 15px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="description" content="Transparent border not working">
<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="item-image" style='background: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/bagiuiani/bagiuiani1003/bagiuiani100300014/15165060-Mellons-Stock-Photo.jpg) no-repeat 20% center; background-size: cover;'>
      </div>
     <div class="item-image" style='background: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/bagiuiani/bagiuiani1003/bagiuiani100300014/15165060-Mellons-Stock-Photo.jpg) no-repeat 20% center; background-size: cover;'>
      </div>
       </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you are probably looking for is [`background-clip`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-clip). Set the value either to `content-box` or `padding-box` and the result is that the background-image won't continue under the border (which by the way is caused by the fact that the image dimensions are different from the dimensions of the div and `background-size: cover`).

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
}
.overlay {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #808080;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f00;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.overlay .item-image {
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 45vw;
  width: 45vw;
  margin-left: 4vw;
  border: 15px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="description" content="Transparent border not working">

<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="item-image" style='background: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/bagiuiani/bagiuiani1003/bagiuiani100300014/15165060-Mellons-Stock-Photo.jpg) no-repeat 20% center; background-size: cover; background-clip: content-box'>
    </div>
    <div class="item-image" style='background: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/bagiuiani/bagiuiani1003/bagiuiani100300014/15165060-Mellons-Stock-Photo.jpg) no-repeat 20% center; background-size: cover; background-clip: content-box'>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Just in case I misunderstood the question and you want to have a transparent border on all sides, you could do it like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
}
.overlay {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #808080;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f00;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.overlay .item-image {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 45vw;
  width: 45vw;
  margin-left: 4vw;
}
.overlay .item-image:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 15px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<meta name="description" content="Transparent border not working">

<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="item-image" style='background: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/bagiuiani/bagiuiani1003/bagiuiani100300014/15165060-Mellons-Stock-Photo.jpg) no-repeat 20% center; background-size: cover;'>
    </div>
    <div class="item-image" style='background: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/bagiuiani/bagiuiani1003/bagiuiani100300014/15165060-Mellons-Stock-Photo.jpg) no-repeat 20% center; background-size: cover;'>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's it: background-clip !! Thanks!